# Playing random wav files with winsound issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, audio, pycharm, winsound

I am pretty new to Python.
I've been trying to make a sciript that plays random WAV files from a specific folder whenever run.
if I try a single wav file it works all fine but doesn't work with random/file. I have tried pygame and some other modules for audio but I ran issues with every single one. For example pygame refuses to open a WAV or MP3 file. When I print it I can see that it does choose random files but windows does a "bring" sound and doesn't play the audio. Really basic probably but I somehow cannot fix this.
Thanks for the help.

```
import winsound
import random
import os
winsound.PlaySound(random.choice(os.listdir("D:/randomsoundfolder/dem/")), winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for duplicate post before. You can check out pya, example in : https://stackoverflow.com/a/60902249/4930109

As playing wav requires PyAudio(wrapper for portaudio), For windows users, you can install the wheels from : https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pyaudio

However, I find the easiest way is to just use Anaconda to install PyAudio as it will install non python library:

```
conda install pyaudio
```

I would recommend you to use Anaconda for handling your Python environment as it will give your a much more clean way to organise each project as they might need different Python versions, different dependencies and so on. There are many benefits of Anaconda.

Then

```
pip install pya
```

Then you can follow the first link to play the wav file. If you want to play mp3 then you will need ffmpeg as well, please out pya (https://github.com/interactive-sonification/pya) for instruction on installing ffmpeg for your OS.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
import winsound
import random
import os
import glob

#Create a placeholder for the soundfile that will be selected
soundfile = ''
 
# Path to the sound file directory, in this example we will use a random wav file from the Windows Media folder.
path = 'C:\Windows\Media'
 
# Extract the list of filenames from the path that are wav files only.
soundfiles = glob.glob(path + '\*.wav', recursive=False)
 
# Loop to print the filenames and create a list of the soundfiles
for filename in soundfiles:
    print(filename)

# Pick a random sound file from a list
soundfile = random.choice(soundfiles)

print("Play a random sound") 
winsound.PlaySound(soundfile, winsound.SND_ASYNC)
```